# Cannot access InAppBrowser url

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I installed the latest version of the InAppBrowser plugin (1.3.0) in a Phonegap 5.5.0 project. However I cannot access the `event.url` property. The error it throws is: Permission denied to access property "toJSON".

```
View = React.createClass({
    onAction: {
        this.setState({
            // Some state
        }, (function (_this) {
            loginUrl = "url";
            _this.popup = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(loginUrl, "_blank", "hardwareback=no,zoom=no,toolbar=no");
            _this.popup.addEventListener("loadstop", _this.onBrowserLoad);
        })(this));
    },
    onBrowserLoad: function (event) {
        // This line throws the error
        console.warn(event.url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show more code please

Comment: @manzapanza I just edited my question.